# How to create a two row navigation bar with a logo in the middle

Tags: html, css

I am having problems creating a two row navigation bar using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

This is what I want my navbar to look like :
[image]

However, the logo seems to overlap the links on the right-hand side, which do not what I want. 
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div id="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> </li>
        <li style="padding:0;"><a href="#" style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top:0;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x115" alt=""  width="100%"></a>
          <li><a href="#">01283 575 671</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Join Now </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_first">Facilties</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_blank"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav_last">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
* { box-sizing:border-box }

body {
    margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

#top-bar {
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 650px;
    min-height: 50px;
  background: #FFDE00;
}

#top-bar div ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#top-bar div ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    width: 20%;
  background: #FFDE00;
    font-weight:500;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}

#top-bar div ul li:first-child{
  width:40%;
}

#top-bar div ul li:last-child{
  background:#081F2D;
}


#top-bar div ul li a {
    display: block;
    color:#081F2D;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:17px;
}

#top-bar > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a{
  color:#FFDE00;
}

#nav {
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 500px;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-left:0;
}

.nav-bg{
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;

  background-color: #ccc;
}
#nav a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color:#081F2D;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#nav .nav_blank { width: 250px; padding: 15px 0; }
#nav .nav_first { padding-left: 0; }
#nav .nav_last { padding-right: 0; }
```

The codepen to my problem is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/VEyXVJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `div` and `span` instead of `ul` and `li`. Also, divide all stuff in 3 parts - left, center and right. That will make your task easier resulting below.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="top-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-right-container">
        <div class="left-container">
          <span><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> </span>
        </div> 
        <div class="right-container">
          <span><a href="#">01283 575 671</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Join Now </a></span>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="center-container">
        <span style="padding:0;"><a href="#" style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top:0;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x115" alt=""  width="100%"></a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-right-nav">
      <div class="left-nav">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" class="nav_first">Facilties</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Timetable</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Blog</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-nav">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#">The Team</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Events</a></span>
          <span><a href="#" class="nav_last">Contact Us</a></span> 
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="center-nav">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing:border-box }

body {
    margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.left-container, .center-container, .right-container{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  width: calc(50% - 125px);
}
.left-container{
  left:0;
      height: 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.left-container span {
  margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.center-container{
  width:250px;
  height:115px;
  z-index:2;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.right-container{
  right:0;
      height: 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.right-container span:last-child{
  background:#081F2D;
   width:40%;
  float:right;
}
.right-container span:last-child a{
  color:#FFDE00;
}
.left-right-container{
  background: #FFDE00;
  height: inherit;
}
.left-container span, .right-container span {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-weight:500;
  text-transform:uppercase;
   width:59%;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
.left-container span a, .right-container span a {
    display: block;
    color:#081F2D;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:17px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

#top-bar {
    float: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 650px;
    min-height: 50px;
  background: #FFDE00;
}

/******************/

.nav-bg{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index:1;
}
.left-right-nav{
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  height: inherit;
}
.left-nav, .center-nav, .right-nav {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 125px);
}
.left-nav{
  left:0;
}
.center-nav{
  width:250px;
  height:50px;
  z-index:1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.right-nav{
  right:0;
}
.left-nav div, .right-nav div{
  margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align:right;
}
.left-nav div span{
}
.right-nav div span{
  float:left;
}
.left-nav div span, .right-nav div span{
  display: inline-block; 
}
.left-nav span a, .right-nav span a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color:#081F2D;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

[image]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPGRvm

Answer (score 1):

Redo your structure as follows by implementing CSS-Grids

CSS part:

```
 #parent_column
{
  grid-template-columns:1fr 0.61fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
}

#first_column
{
  grid-column: 1;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#second_column
{
  grid-column: 2;
}

#third_column
{
  grid-column: 3;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

HTML as

```
<div id="parent_column">
  <div id="first_column">
    <div style="background-color: rebeccapurple;">Top Bar Content on Left</div>
    <div style="background-color: gold;">Bottom Bar Content on Left</div>
  </div>
  <div id="second_column">
    <a href="#" style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top:0;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x115" alt=""
        width="100%"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="third_column">
    <div style="background-color: red;">Top Bar Content on Left</div>
    <div style="background-color: pink">Bottom Bar Content on Left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]
CSS-Grid is now supported on 87.85% of the browsers and for IE browser you need to add the prefix ms-

For more reference of browser [support on CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: Oh, you beat me, I was writing the same code for a few minutes :3

Comment: Apologies :) I felt the OP wasn't aware of Grids maybe so I started to write to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any options except using `grid` template or spit navigation into two blocks - left and right.

In case of grid this can help you: [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: the reason I did not use CSS grid because it's not supported on the older browsers.

Comment: @JafarSalami https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid mostly supported. if you need even older browser - then you probably should split navigation into two columns. You can look into bootstrap columns, or maybe make your own with simple ``float:left/right``

Comment: You actually you can look what @richard-pariath did.